# Result set depends on a column value change (prior date)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the name indicators and four column which stores the data monthly. Now I want to analyse the data. First I compared some values about one year (13 months) and I found out that I even need the last value change of a column to decide which result should be taken (which makes the things so complex).

Here the SQL command for one year and part of the result set:

```
SELECT e.* FROM indicators AS e ORDER BY e.date DESC LIMIT 13

date            interest_rate inflation_rate exchange_rate
"2018-04-02"    0.0           1.1            1.2321
[...]
"2017-04-03"    0.0           2.0            1.0691
```

The problem come up when I found out that the intrest_rate colum doesn't have the last value of change in the result set. After looking inside stackoverflow I come to a further SQL command:

```
SELECT c.* FROM indicators AS c WHERE (c.date >= 
    ( SELECT b.date FROM indicators AS b WHERE b.interest_rate <>
        ( SELECT a.interest_rate FROM indicators AS a WHERE b.date < a.date ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
      ORDER BY b.date DESC  LIMIT 1 ) 
    )

date            interest_rate inflation_rate exchange_rate
"2016-03-01"    0.05          0.3            1.0888
"2016-04-01"    0.0          -0.2            1.1385
[...]
"2017-04-03"    0.0           2.0            1.0691
```

The problem is that there are two queries where the correct date should be found. At the moment the date is the 1st of March 2016.

After playing arround with min(), max(), LEFT JOIN etc I come to a solution with UNION.

```
SELECT result1.* FROM 
( SELECT c.* FROM indicators AS c WHERE (c.date >= 
    ( SELECT b.date FROM indicators AS b WHERE b.interest_rate <>
        ( SELECT a.interest_rate FROM indicators AS a WHERE b.date < a.date ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
      ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
    ) 
) AS result1
UNION 
SELECT result2.* FROM ( SELECT e.* FROM indicators AS e ORDER BY e.date DESC LIMIT 13) AS result2
```

If looks for me that this solution will work if the rate change is outside the 13 months. Will be the result correct if the interest_rate change is inside the 13 months? I there maybe a simpler solution?

EDIT: There is point system.
If the inflation rate is lower than the inflation rate of one year - one point
If the exchange rate is lower than the exchange rate of one year - one point.
Was the last interest rate decreased - one point.

Here the complete result that until the first interest rate change:

```
date            intr_r  infl_r  exchange_rate
"2016-03-01"    "0.05"  "0.3"   "1.0888"
"2016-04-01"    "0.0"   "-0.2"  "1.1385"
"2016-05-02"    "0.0"   "0.0"   "1.1403"
"2016-06-01"    "0.0"   "-0.2"  "1.1154"
"2016-07-01"    "0.0"   "-0.1"  "1.1102"
"2016-08-01"    "0.0"   "0.1"   "1.1113"
"2016-09-01"    "0.0"   "0.2"   "1.1132"
"2016-10-04"    "0.0"   "0.2"   "1.1161"
"2016-11-01"    "0.0"   "0.4"   "1.0946"
"2016-12-01"    "0.0"   "0.5"   "1.0635"
"2017-01-02"    "0.0"   "0.6"   "1.0541"
"2017-02-01"    "0.0"   "1.1"   "1.0755"
"2017-03-01"    "0.0"   "1.8"   "1.0597"
"2017-04-03"    "0.0"   "2.0"   "1.0691"
"2017-05-02"    "0.0"   "1.5"   "1.093"
"2017-06-01"    "0.0"   "1.9"   "1.1221"
"2017-07-03"    "0.0"   "1.4"   "1.1412"
"2017-08-01"    "0.0"   "1.3"   "1.1727"
"2017-09-01"    "0.0"   "1.3"   "1.1825"
"2017-10-02"    "0.0"   "1.5"   "1.1806"
"2017-11-01"    "0.0"   "1.5"   "1.1638"
"2017-12-01"    "0.0"   "1.4"   "1.1849"
"2018-01-02"    "0.0"   "1.5"   "1.1993"
"2018-02-01"    "0.0"   "1.4"   "1.2457"
"2018-03-01"    "0.0"   "1.3"   "1.2214"
"2018-04-02"    "0.0"   "1.1"   "1.2321"
```

I wanted to calculate the points as an indicator for an investment.

Comment: I baffled by what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I added the complete result set if the previous interest rate could be seen. The desired result should be a query to see the latest interest rate value and at least the last 13 months. That was my intention yesterday.